# Why nodemailer does not work in playwright project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, playwright, nodemailer

I have implemented a **reporter.ts** file in my play wright project. I want to send an email to some developers at the end of the running tests. But although I have tried several ways and read the documentation of `nodemailer` module, but no email is sent, and no error is also shown.

Here is my full code of **reporter.ts** file:

```
    import { FullConfig, FullResult, Reporter, Suite, TestCase, TestResult, TestStatus, TestError } from "@playwright/test/reporter";
import * as fs from "fs"; // The node:fs module enables interacting with the file system in a way modeled on standard POSIX functions
import date from 'date-and-time';
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import cron from "node-cron";
import { spawn } from "child_process";
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import { OAUTH_CLIENTID, 
    OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET, 
    OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN,
    OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    REDIRECT_URL } from "./constant/authorization";

/**
 * To run this file use the below command:
 * npx playwright test --reporter=reporter.ts
 */

// Set up Auth2 client
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    OAUTH_CLIENTID,
    OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIRECT_URL
)

// Set the access token
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN,
});

//  Create the transporter using OAuth2 authentication
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:  587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: 'sepanta.pw@gmail.com',
        clientId: OAUTH_CLIENTID,
        clientSecret: OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN,
        accessToken: oAuth2Client.getAccessToken(),
    }
});


class MyReporter implements Reporter {
    modifiedResults: { test: string; status: TestStatus; executionTime: number; errors: TestError[] }[];

    constructor() {
        this.modifiedResults = [];
    }

    onBegin(config: FullConfig<{}, {}>, suite: Suite): void {
        console.log(`Execution of ${suite.allTests().length} tests`);
    }

    async onEnd(result: FullResult): Promise<void> {
        console.log(`Execution finished with status of ${result.status}`);

        // this.sendEmail();
        const now = new Date(); // Get the current date and time
        const dateStringFolder = date.format(now, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        const dateStringFile = date.format(now, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM');
        const folderPath = `pw_res_${dateStringFolder}`;

        if (!fs.existsSync(folderPath)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(folderPath);
        }
        const formattedResults = this.modifiedResults.map((test) => ({
            title: test.test,
            status: test.status,
            errors: test.errors
        }));
        // console.log(`The formated result is: ${formattedResults}`);

        // Format the test results in a more interpretable way
        const formattedEmailContent = formattedResults
            .map((result) => `Title: ${result.title}\nStatus: ${result.status}\nErrors: ${result.errors}`)
            .join("\n\n");
        

        const randomInt = Math.random(); 
        fs.appendFileSync(`${folderPath}/test-result-${dateStringFile}.txt`, formattedEmailContent);

        await this.sendEmail();
        // console.log("HA HA HA!")
    }

    onTestBegin(test: TestCase, result: TestResult): void {
        console.log(`Execution of ${test.title} started.`);
    }

    onTestEnd(test: TestCase, result: TestResult): void {
        const now = new Date(); // Get the current date and time
        const dateString = date.format(now, 'YYYY-MM-DD_HH-mm-ss'); // Format the date and time into a string

        const execTime = result.duration;

        const data = {
            test: test.title,
            status: result.status,
            executionTime: execTime,
            errors: result.errors
        };
        this.modifiedResults.push(data);
    }

    async sendEmail(): Promise<void> 
        // Code for sending email
    {
        console.log(this.modifiedResults);
        // Extract the title and status of each test
        const formattedResults = this.modifiedResults.map((test) => ({
            title: test.test,
            status: test.status
        }));
        // console.log(`The formated result is: ${formattedResults}`);

        // Format the test results in a more interpretable way
        const formattedEmailContent = formattedResults
            .map((result) => `Title: ${result.title}\nStatus: ${result.status}`)
            .join("\n\n");
        
        console.log(`The formated email content is: ${formattedEmailContent}`);

        
        // Compose the email
        const mailOptions = {
            from: "sepanta.pw@gmail.com",
            to: "aylin.naebzadeh@gmail.com",
            subject: "PlayWright Test Results",
            text: `Test Results:\n\n${formattedEmailContent}`
        };
        console.log("---------------- send email ---------------")
        // Send the email
        await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
            if (error) {
                console.error('Error sending email: ', error);
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent: ', info.response);
            }
        });
    };
}

// Export the MyReporter class
module.exports = MyReporter;
```

The output:

```
(SepantaEnv) D:\ABDAL\sepanta\PlayWright>npx playwright test --reporter=reporter.ts
Execution of 2 tests
Execution of login started.
Execution of failed login started.
Execution finished with status of passed
[
  {
    test: 'failed login',
    status: 'passed',
    executionTime: 6754,
    errors: []
  },
  { test: 'login', status: 'passed', executionTime: 7141, errors: [] }
]
The formated email content is: Title: failed login
Status: passed

Title: login
Status: passed
---------------- send email ---------------
HA HA HA!

(SepantaEnv) D:\ABDAL\sepanta\PlayWright>
```

I will be really grateful for any help, since I am stuck in this problem for about one week.

Comment: "*no email is sent*" Can you be specific about what evidence you're using to make this assertion? Is it that the message doesn't appear in the "Sent items" folder of the sending account? Something else?

Comment: Yes exactly... There is no email in "Sent items" of **sepanta.pw@gmail.com** account, and also no email from this account in "Spam" or "Inbox" of **aylin.naebzadeh@gmail.com**.

Comment: sendEmail() is async function, but you are not awaiting it.
Check out https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-reporter await reporter.onEnd(result); understands from promise, so you can declare onEnd as async and use await or return promise.

Comment: I have defined it as async. But the problem is not solved yet.@Infern0